# Elementary number theory in modular functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying Apostol Dirichlet series and Modular functions in number theory and I am struck on Ch -2 Problem 17. It is a problem of elementary number theory but I am not able to think about it.

> Question: if a, b, n are integers with n greater than or equal to 1 and
>    ( a, b, n)  =1 , then prove that the congruence ax- by=1 ( mod n)  has exactly n solutions,  distinct mod n.

---

I tried using solutions of diophantine equation ax+by= c but can't do it.  Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gcd(a,n)=d$. Then $\gcd(b,d)=1$, so $by+1\equiv0\bmod d$ has a unique solution mod $d$, which lifts to $n/d$ solutions mod $n$. For each of those $n/d$ values of $y$, $(a/d)x\equiv(by+1)/d\bmod{n/d}$ has a unique solution mod $n/d$, which lifts to $d$ solutions mod $n$. So we have $n/d$ values of $y$, and, for each of them, $d$ values of $x$, hence, all told, $(n/d)d=n$ solutions.